# devexpress RowSeparatorHeight with merge cell

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

I want a RowSeparatorHeight after the merged rows only

[this image for problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzIg2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `RowSeparatorHeight` you simply have to do following:

GridView1.RowSeparatorHeight = INTEGERVALUE, so in case you would like to set height of 10 between rows you should do following:

```
GridView1.RowSeparatorHeight = 10
```